# Run time Fatal error in currency converter android app

Tags: java, android

The application gets crashed when i press the buttons. Each convert"country name" function is a button. I'll post the error in the comment. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void convertIndia(View view){ convert(64.7,"Rupees"); }
    public void convertEurope(View view){ convert(0.85,"Euros"); }
    public void convertBritish(View view){ convert(0.78,"Pounds"); }
    public void convertUae(View view) { convert(3.67,"Dhiram"); }
    public void convertCanada(View view){ convert(1.26,"Ca Dollors"); }     
    public void convertAustralia(View view) { convert(1.26,"Aus Dollors"); }

    public void convert(double other,String country){

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value);
        Double usdValue = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

        Log.i("USDVAL",usdValue.toString());
        Log.i("EDITTEXT",editText.toString());

        Double finalvalue = usdValue * other;

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("%.2f", finalvalue) + " " + country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

error log

08-26 12:04:46.140 2387-2387/com.fellowwebster.currencyconverter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.fellowwebster.currencyconverter, PID: 2387
                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.fellowwebster.currencyconverter.MainActivity.convert(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                                   at com.fellowwebster.currencyconverter.MainActivity.convertIndia(MainActivity.java:18)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/india"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/british"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/value"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/british"
    android:onClick="convertIndia"
    android:text="IND_Rupee"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="131dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="70dp" />
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.fellowwebster.currencyconverter, PID: 2387
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)

Comment: Please share your xml code @Dhanasekar

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to update or provide additional information. Please don't post it in comments.

Comment: Ok, newbie here sorry. @MikeM.

Comment: No problem. Please provide the _complete_ stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: It would seem that the `<EditText>` with ID `value` is not in the `activity_main` layout, either directly, or in an `<include>`d layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try onClickListener instead of android:onClick.
Example:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);   
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        callYourMethodHere();
    }
});
```

Place this inside onCreate and you are good to go

Comment: This is not the issue. The Exception message would be different if the `onClick` method couldn't be found.